# Start very wide table scrolled to the right in gt and quarto

Tags: r, gt, quarto

I don't even quite know how to start researching this but say I have a table that is *very* wide. If I were to render that table using `{gt}` in `Quarto` you get a handy scroll bar at the bottom of the table so you can scroll across the table.

````
---
title: "wide-tables"
format: html
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

table <- quakes %>% 
  group_by(stations) %>% 
  summarise(mag = mean(mag)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = stations, 
    values_from = mag
)

gt(table)
```
````

**My question: is there any way to have that scroll bar default to *all the way to the right*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some javascript code to do this. And to do this for a specific table, wrap the code chunk (which will generate the `gt` table) with pandoc divs specifying a css class `wide_tab`.

````
---
title: "wide-tables"
format: html
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
include-after-body: scrollbar_start.html
---

::: {.wide_tab}

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

table <- quakes %>% 
  group_by(stations) %>% 
  summarise(mag = mean(mag)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = stations, 
    values_from = mag
)

gt(table)
```

:::
````

**scrollbar_start.html**

```
<script>
  function scrollbar_starting() {
    let gt_table = document.querySelector(".wide_tab .gt_table");
    let parent = gt_table.parentElement;
    let width = parent.scrollWidth;
    parent.scrollLeft = width;
  }
  
  window.onload = scrollbar_starting();
</script>
```

---

[image: a super wide egt table with scrollbar starting at right side]

---